# mysqli_stmt_bind_param returns no feedback

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to catch the error that an unsuccessful bind statement result in, which is why I am deliberately not passing in the types to the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` function. Please see the code snippet below

```
$email = 'test@test.com';
$password = 'password';
if (!(mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt , '' , $email, $password))) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt) . ") " . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) . "<br>";
}
```

However, the `mysqli_stmt_errno` returns 0 and the `mysqli_stmt_error()` returns an empty string.

PHP gives a warning saying

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Invalid type or no types specified in C:\wamp\www\test\database1.php on line 28

Why do I not get feedback from the database?

Comment: why do you want to catch it?

Comment: Coz I am learning by experimenting with it. Hence, I'd like to see what kind of error it returns when things go wrong.

Comment: Sounds sensible. though, you already have the error, don't you?

Comment: I was under the impression, that the database ought to return an error about an unsuccessful bind and wasn't sure why it didn't. I have my answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

because binding has nothing to do with database.

Answer (score 0):

The bind parameters are sent along with the execute statement, and not before. The bind and execute happens in a single SQL statement, even though there are 2 PHP functions for it. Its only after the execute statement has run that the database is in a position to give feedback about an unsuccessful bind. Hope this helps anyone who might wonder regarding the same.

Comment: your conclusion contradicts with your experience

Comment: I did a network capture to see this and then arrived at the conclusion. I do come with enough experience at the networking level to interpret network traffic. This question was posted before I did the capture. I promise :-)

Comment: Beside capturing events it's essential to interpret them properly. Most likely you are confusing binding with execution. And according to your question you have  feedback about an unsuccessful bind without execution at all.

Comment: The question says `Why do I not get a feedback from the database?`. I do not get a feedback about an unsuccessful bind. From what I have understood, the bind parameters are sent to the database at the time of execution in a single MySQL packet.

Comment: Are you? What does `"mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Invalid type"` mean then?

Comment: That is a PHP warning. I was specifically asking Why do I not get a feedback from the **database**?

Comment: because it's entirely PHP's business, you've been told. and no other binding is done beyond this point

Comment: Its not entirely only PHP's business. The binding happens at the time the SQL statement gets executed. See this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-stmt-execute.html

Comment: yes. this is called execution, not binding. it seems you are still confusing these two different matters.

Comment: Would you agree when I say that the `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`, has an effect on the contents of a MySQL execute statement?

Comment: Not before you solve the mutual exclusivity of your own statements: 1. " mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Invalid type" and 2. "Its only after the execute statement has run that the database is in a position to give feedback about an unsuccessful bind. "

Comment: 1. " mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Invalid type" - PHP error. Nothing to do with the database feedback. Please stop cross referring it with 2.

Comment: it's **binding** error. the only binding happened in the process. Means your speculations on "Its only after the execute statement has run that the database is in a position to give feedback about an unsuccessful bind." are plainly wrong. Besides, you've no proof for such a statement. You just invented some "secondary binding" out of nowhere.

Comment: Look at the parameter section here - http://imgur.com/DhLwNOk. This is the parameter binding that is dictated by the mysqli_stmt_bind_param function.

Comment: That's query data. The result of binding. By the way, did you get any proof for the "feedback about an unsuccessful bind." happened after query execution?

Comment: Look. You're putting too much meaning in the binding. Think it from the *multiple execution* perspective. You're binding only *once*! And then binding is not involved at al - only execution. It's quite a trifle technical operation, entirely on PHP side. Any feedback you can get after execute is feedback on execute, not bind.